# NodeJS Crypto - hashing n times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, hash

I need to hash a hash (H(H(H(...))) about 100'000 times in NodeJS I've come up with three solutions but they each have problems.

Can anyone come up with a solution that is not slow, crashes or blocks? - preferably without saying threading, but I'm open to that.

Note : this is more of a javascript / NodeJS problem then a crypto one

The first one is the fastest but blocks for 232ms so that's no good.

```
hash = function(data, n)
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(data === undefined || n < 1) resolve(false);

        while(n--)
        {
            //console.log('iteration', n, data)
            let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
            hash.update(data);
            data = hash.digest();
        }
        resolve(data)

    }).catch(err=>{return err})
}
```

The next one contains two solutions (2&3), the only difference is a single line of code. One overflows the stack and the other is very slow, as commented.

```
hash = function(data, n)
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(data === undefined || n < 1) resolve(false);

        (function it() {
            //console.log('iteration', n, data)
            let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
            hash.on('readable', () => { 
                let t = hash.read();
                if(t == null) return;
                data = t;
                hash.read();
                if(--n > 0) {
                    //2. gets me to n=100000 but n=10000 takes 15 seconds!!!
                    setTimeout(it, 0) 

                    //3. Very fast but Maximum call stack size exceeded when 
                    //   n=641 so no good and I'm not going to increase the 
                    //   limit just to force it.
                    //it();
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
            hash.write(data);
            hash.end();
        })();
    }).catch(err=>{return err})
}
```

Comment: if you're iterating 100K times that's going to have some cost in time. 232ms doesn't seem unreasonable to me for that amount of hash objects.

Comment: Yeah I agree the performance is not bad on my desktop pc, however if it stops all other events from running it's a bit of a problem for the other users. I'm having a peruse of this https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads  but would just prefer a node only solution and without forking the whole thing.